# What is @babel/plugin-transform-classes?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I run Google PageSpeed Insights on my site, and it reports an issue that is "Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers", as below:

[image]

I have no idea of what is `@babel/plugin-transform-classes`, so I search online and it seems babel is a [JavaScript compiler](https://babeljs.io/)  and @babel/plugin-transform-classes is a [plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-classes).

But I don't know or install the compiler and the plugin, why there will be such an issue?

Comment: It's right on top of that page you linked: *NOTE: This plugin is included in `@babel/preset-env`*. From the information you present I cannot tell 100%, but most probably this is the preset that you asset build pipeline uses for Babel.

Comment: Babel compiles modern JS into code which can work on old terrible awful browsers like IE 11. You choose the plugins that you want to work with. That one "compiles ES2015 classes to ES5". If that's your site WP might be using it somewhere.

Comment: @Andy, so you mean all WordPress site will has such an issue?

Comment: @alancc, it was a wild guess. I honestly have no idea. You're not using babel, but it's apparently in the pipeline somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

- A **babel plugin** that **fix** some **Javascript** errors for **legacy browser**
- You **cannot fix this error** on your own, not if you're using Wordpress or any framework at least.

### Long answer

#### What is babel

[Babel is a JavaScript compiler](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) which is used by framework to make code understandable for older browser.

#### What is @babel/plugin-transform-classes

This is [a babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-classes), which is included in `@babel/preset-env`.

It does

> - Transpiles classes using `SuperClass.apply(/* ... */)`, but native classes aren't callable and thus throw in this case.
> - Some built-in functions (like `Array`) always return a new object. Instead of returning it, Babel should treat it as the new this.

##### In

```js
class Test {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  logger() {
    console.log("Hello", this.name);
  }
}
```

##### Out

```js
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }
}

var Test = (function() {
  function Test(name) {
    _classCallCheck(this, Test);

    this.name = name;
  }

  Test.prototype.logger = function logger() {
    console.log("Hello", this.name);
  };

  return Test;
})();
```

#### Can I fix this problem on my own?

No, since a lot of library are still using babel, you'll have to wait for them to move on.

So you're safe to ignore this issue.